# How to remove condition check in the where clause statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I would like to know how to use if/else or case statement in the below query or anything that could achieve the purpose.
The idea is that, whenever a keyword is NULL or blank, I don't want to include the `pv.AdminPost = 1 and pv.IsStaff = 1` condition in the Where statement.

Is there any way to do it? Thank you.

```
    ;WITH cte 
            AS (SELECT fv.Id, fv.[Description] 
                FROM FeedView fv
                WHERE  (fv.Id =  @PostId OR fv.[Description] LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%' OR @Keyword IS NULL ) AND fv.ForUserId = @UserId
                UNION 
                SELECT pv.Id, pv.[Description]  
                FROM PublicView pv
                WHERE @InculdePublicPosts = 1 -- This acts as an off switch to decide whether to include public post or not.    
                      OR pv.AdminPost = 1 OR pv.IsStaff = 1 -- how to remove this condition when Keyword is NULL or empty
                      AND (pv.Id =  @PostId OR pv.[Description] LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%' OR @keyword IS NULL )
            )

SELECT cte.Id, cte.[Description]
FROM .....
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

You must use proper paranthesis and `OR` condition as follows:

```
WHERE @InculdePublicPosts = 1 
  AND ((@keyword IS NULL OR @keyword = '')  OR pv.AdminPost = 1 OR pv.IsStaff = 1)
  AND (pv.Id =  @PostId OR pv.[Description] LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%' OR @keyword IS NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
AND (ISNULL(keyword, '') = '' OR (pv.AdminPost = 1 OR pv.IsStaff = 1))
```

**Explain:**

- Using [`ISNULL()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_isnull.asp) function to get the empty value in case that `keyword` is `null`.
- If `keyword is NULL or blank`, then the remaining condition will not run thanks to `OR` condition. Example:

```
false or true  --> true
true  or false --> true
true  or true  --> true
false or false --> false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^! @Hoang Minh